# Conversion of a Tensorflow Model with Preprocess layer to TFLite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, keras-layer

I'm trying to build a TFLite Audio Classification Model and for that I have integrated Preprocess Function with the Model in a single file.

The following code is to combine my model with the preprocess function.

```
class TFLiteModel(tf.Module):
    """
    TensorFlow Lite model that takes input tensors and applies:
        – a preprocessing model
        – the CNN model 
    """
def __init__(self,my_model, my_pp_fn):
    """
    Initializes the TFLiteModel with the specified preprocessing model.
    """
    super(TFLiteModel, self).__init__()

    # Load the feature generation and main models

    self.prep_inputs_3 = my_pp_fn()

    self.model_3       = my_model

@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name = 'inputs')])
def __call__(self, inputs):
    """
    Applies the feature generation model and main model to the input tensors.

    Args:
        inputs: Input tensor of type string.

    Returns:
        an array of array depicting True or False output but the digits '1' or '0'.
    """

    x3 = self.prep_inputs_3(inputs)
    x3 = tf.reshape(x3, [-1, 128, 384, 1])
    outputs_3 = self.model_3(x3) 
    
    
    # Return a dictionary with the output tensor
    return outputs_3
```

The following is to combine the model and the featuregen (preprocess function).

```
tflite_keras_model = TFLiteModel(
    model, FeatureGen
)
```

The following is the preprocess function:

```
class FeatureGen(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FeatureGen, self).__init__()

def call(self, file):
  ############# Reading the file and converting it to audio tensor
    file_bytes = tf.io.read_file(file)
    # Decode the audio
    audio, sample_rate = tf.audio.decode_wav(file_bytes , desired_channels=1)
    # converting the loaded tensors to float32
    audio = tf.cast(audio, tf.float32)
    # Removing the trailing axis (axis reduction)
    audio = tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)
    # Computing the mean and sd (bringing it closer to librosa result)
    # Goes from 44100Hz to 22050hz - amplitude of the audio signal
    sample_rate = tf.cast(sample_rate, dtype=tf.int64)
    audio = tfio.audio.resample(audio, rate_in=sample_rate, rate_out=22050)

  ############## converting audio tensor to spectrogram
 
    # Get the desired height and width of the spectrogram
    spec_height = 128
    spec_width = 384
    
    # Get the length of the audio and calculate the hop length for the STFT
    audio_len = tf.shape(audio)[0]
    hop_length = tf.cast((audio_len // (spec_width - 1)), tf.int32)
    
    # Compute the spectrogram and the Mel-scaled spectrogram using TensorFlow-IO
    spec = tfio.audio.spectrogram(audio, nfft=2048, window=2048, stride=hop_length)
    mel_spec = tfio.audio.melscale(spec, rate=22050, mels=spec_height, fmin=500, fmax=10000)
    
    # Convert the Mel-scaled spectrogram to decibels and transpose it to keep it (mel, time)
    db_mel_spec = tfio.audio.dbscale(mel_spec, top_db=80)
    db_mel_spec = tf.transpose(db_mel_spec, perm=[1, 0])
    
    # If the spectrogram is larger than the desired shape, crop it
    if tf.shape(db_mel_spec)[1] > spec_width:
        db_mel_spec = db_mel_spec[:, :spec_width]
    
    # Reshape the spectrogram to the desired shape and return it
    db_mel_spec = tf.reshape(db_mel_spec, [128,384])


    db_mel_spec = tf.expand_dims(db_mel_spec, -1)
 
    return db_mel_spec
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to convert it to a TFLite model.

```
keras_model_converter =tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tflite_keras_model)
keras_model_converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
tflite_model = keras_model_converter.convert()

TFLITE_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Models/model_1_tf.tflite'
with open(TFLITE_PATH, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)[![Error in model.convert()][1]][1]
```

The error log:

```
    WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as feature_gen_7_layer_call_fn, feature_gen_7_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _jit_compiled_convolution_op, _update_step_xla while saving (showing 5 of 5). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConverterError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-7dc47c6ba5c5> in <module>
      1 keras_model_converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tflite_keras_model)
      2 # keras_model_converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
----> 3 tflite_model = keras_model_converter.convert()
      4 
      5 TFLITE_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Models/model_1_tf.tflite'

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    931   def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    932     # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 933     return self._convert_and_export_metrics(convert_func, *args, **kwargs)
    934     # pylint: enable=protected-access
    935 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py in _convert_and_export_metrics(self, convert_func, *args, **kwargs)
    909     self._save_conversion_params_metric()
    910     start_time = time.process_time()
--> 911     result = convert_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    912     elapsed_time_ms = (time.process_time() - start_time) * 1000
    913     if result:

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py in convert(self)
   1340         Invalid quantization parameters.
   1341     
-> 1342     saved_model_convert_result = self._convert_as_saved_model()
   1343     if saved_model_convert_result:
   1344       return saved_model_convert_result

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py in _convert_as_saved_model(self)
   1322           self._convert_keras_to_saved_model(temp_dir))
   1323       if self.saved_model_dir:
-> 1324         return super(TFLiteKerasModelConverterV2,
   1325                      self).convert(graph_def, input_tensors, output_tensors)
   1326     finally:

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py in convert(self, graph_def, input_tensors, output_tensors)
   1133 
   1134     # Converts model.
-> 1135     result = _convert_graphdef(
   1136         input_data=graph_def,
   1137         input_tensors=input_tensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert_phase.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    210         else:
    211           report_error_message(str(converter_error))
--> 212         raise converter_error from None  # Re-throws the exception.
    213       except Exception as error:
    214         report_error_message(str(error))

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert_phase.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    203     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    204       try:
--> 205         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    206       except ConverterError as converter_error:
    207         if converter_error.errors:

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py in convert_graphdef(input_data, input_tensors, output_tensors, **kwargs)
    791       model_flags.output_arrays.append(util.get_tensor_name(output_tensor))
    792 
--> 793   data = convert(
    794       model_flags.SerializeToString(),
    795       conversion_flags.SerializeToString(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py in convert(model_flags_str, conversion_flags_str, input_data_str, debug_info_str, enable_mlir_converter)
    308       for error_data in _metrics_wrapper.retrieve_collected_errors():
    309         converter_error.append_error(error_data)
--> 310       raise converter_error
    311 
    312   return _run_deprecated_conversion_binary(model_flags_str,

ConverterError: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/parallel_for/control_flow_ops.py:214:0: error: 'tf.TensorListReserve' op requires element_shape to be 1D tensor during TF Lite transformation pass
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/parallel_for/control_flow_ops.py:214:0: error: failed to legalize operation 'tf.TensorListReserve' that was explicitly marked illegal
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
<unknown>:0: error: Lowering tensor list ops is failed. Please consider using Select TF ops and disabling `_experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops` flag in the TFLite converter object. For example, converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]\n converter._experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = False
```

I'm totally lost on what this error is and how I can mitigate it. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: So, where is the error? Can you place the full log?

Comment: Apologies for the missing log, I've just added it

Comment: At the last line it proposes what to use. Can you check that?

keras_model_converter =tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tflite_keras_model)
keras_model_converter._experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = False
keras_model_converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
keras_model_converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = keras_model_converter.convert()

TFLITE_PATH = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Models/model_1_tf.tflite'
with open(TFLITE_PATH, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)

Comment: Please did you resolve this?